# Binary Tree - How to traverse recursive without any parameters

Tags: java, recursion, tree, binary-tree

I don't know how to traverse a given binary tree recursively, just by using the following methodes of the tree. For example every TreeNode has an int Value and a getter TreeNode.getValue() and now i want to find the node with the maximum value in the tree. Note that a tree has only a pointer to its currentNode and u can move to the parent, right, left or root node.

My Question:

```
Tree tree;

public int findMaxValue() {
    //how to implement this as recursive function
}
```

The tree class:

```
/**
 * The abstract class for a tree.
 * @author JK, KM
 */
public abstract class Tree {

    /**
     * Moves to the left child of the current node
     * 
     * @return true if left child exists and the move was successful; otherwise
     *         false
     */
    public abstract boolean moveToLeftNode();

    /**
     * Moves to the right child of the current node
     * 
     * @return true if right child exists and the move was successful; otherwise
     *         false
     */
    public abstract boolean moveToRightNode();

    /**
     * Moves to the parent of the current node
     * 
     * @return true if parent exists and the move was successful; otherwise
     *         false
     */
    public abstract boolean moveToParentNode();

    /**
     * @return true if left child exists; otherwise false
     */
    public abstract boolean hasLeftNode();

    /**
     * @return true if right child exists; otherwise false
     */
    public abstract boolean hasRightNode();

    /**
     * @return true if parent exists; otherwise false
     */
    public abstract boolean hasParentNode();

    /**
     * Sets the left child of the current node
     * 
     * @return true if successful; otherwise false (no root set)
     * 
     */
    public abstract boolean setLeftNode(TreeNode node);

    /**
     * Sets the right child of the current node
     * 
     * @return true if successful; otherwise false (no root set)
     * 
     */
    public abstract boolean setRightNode(TreeNode node);

    /**
     * Sets the current node. If the tree is empty, sets the root.
     * 
     */
    public abstract void setCurrentNode(TreeNode node);

    /**
     * @return the current node or null if the tree is empty
     */
    public abstract TreeNode getCurrentNode();

    /**
     * moves to the root node of this tree
     * 
     * @return true if there's a root; otherwise false
     */
    public abstract boolean moveToRoot();

    /**
     * clears the whole tree, which includes deleting all nodes and the root
     * node
     */
    public abstract void clearTree();
```

Comment: i would recommend to have a look at some data structure book. How about Tannenbaum ?

Comment: homework more or less - i solved this problem by creating a sequential list of the tree and iterate over each node. unfortunately we have to use a recursive method.

Answer (score 2):

You can traverse a binary tree recursively like this:

```
public int findMaxValue() {
    return max(this.node.getValue(),
               this.getLeftChild().findMaxValue(),
               this.getRightChild().findMaxValue());
}
```

Implementing this given your `Tree` interface and checking for leaf nodes is left as an exercise.

Comment: Ok, but how can i solve the problem, if a left and a right node exist? I can either move the tree to the left node or to the right node.

Comment: @Chris You have a method called `hasLeftNode()` and a method called `hasRightNode()` defined in the interface, use those to check if you can move to the left or right.

Comment: The datamodel doesn't offer any getters for the children. If i want to get the left node, i must use something like this: tree.moveToLeftNode; TreeNode node = tree.getCurrentNode; tree.moveToParentNode

Comment: @Chris exactly, why don't you try to implement it like that?